# HP 110-023wp desktop computer

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

The specification states that it has 1 PCIe half-length slot that can be used on [this](http://www.walmart.com/ip/HP-Black-110-023-Desktop-PC-Bundle-with-Intel-Pentium-G2020T-Processor-8GB-Memory-20-Monitor-1TB-Hard-Drive-and-Window-8-Operating-System/24699992) computer.  I am wanting to put a graphics card in the case, as I don't like the Intel onboard HD2500 graphics chip.  **Can the mini slot be used for a graphics card if get an adapter to make slot a pci-ex1 slot?  Can this even be done?**

Comment: I edited your question to make more sense, and remove the thanks messages; you thank people for assistance by upvoting answers, or leaving comments.

Answer (score 1):

According to [other](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=97313) [sites](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/205984-33-card-slot), the easy answer is no.

The main concern is fitting it in physically. Yes, there are adapters to make it fit, if it's a small video card; however, power can become an issue. Because of that, I'd say no, it's not recommended, but try at your own risk (and likely void any warranty).

Having said that, and looking at the specs/reviews, I'd be wary of this PC doing any sort of decent graphics at an acceptable speed.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of PCI-E 1x graphics cards if you look for them.

One of [these](http://www.hisdigital.com/un/product2-675.shtml) for example.

Alternatively you can still purchase (for a premium) PCI video cards.